# siteUrl config and Control Panel conflict

Tags: siteurl

I have set up environments in my config file and included a different siteUrl for each. This is so I can change the navigation on the fly.

I have noticed however that siteUrl when defined in the CP is being used instead of the defined value in the config file. I was under the impression that the CP setting for siteUrl got ignored. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using the same database across both environments - would that be an issue?

```
return array(
     '*' => array(
         // ...
     ),
     // Local Dev
     'test.dev' => array(
         // ...
         'devMode' => true,
         'environmentVariables' => array(
             'assetsBasePath' => '/Users/joebloggs/Sites/work/example/shop/assets/',
             'assetsUrl' => 'http://test.dev/shop/assets/',
             'siteUrl'  => 'http://test.dev/',
         )
     ),
     // Live Dev
     'test.example.com' => array(
         // ...
         'environmentVariables' => array(
             'assetsUrl' => 'http://test.example.com/shop/assets/',
             'assetsBasePath' => '/home/example/public_html/shop/assets/',
             'siteUrl'  => 'http://test.example.com/',
         )
     ),
);
```

Answer (score 5):

The `siteUrl` config setting is not meant to be added under `environmentVariables`.

```php
'test.dev' => array(
    'siteUrl' => 'http://test.dev/',
    'environmentVariables' => array(
        // ...
    ),
    // ...
)
```

Answer (score 2):

This seems to solve the problem:

```
define('SERVER_NAME', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
 if (!isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) || $_SERVER['HTTPS'] != "on") {
     define('SITE_URL', "http://".SERVER_NAME . '/');
 } else {
     define('SITE_URL', "https://".SERVER_NAME . '/');
 }

 return array(
     '*' => array(
         'siteUrl' => SITE_URL,
     ),
```